# Square root of negative

Tags: math, operators, sqrt

I'm a bit puzzled by these results:

result of calculating sq rt of negative number
[image: result of calculating sq rt of negative number]

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: What programming language is that? Please tag the question accordingly and paste the code into the question.

Comment: Probably the main issue here is whether `-a**b` means `-(a**b)` or `(-a)**b`. In your screenshot it looks like it means `-(a**b)`.

Comment: Perhaps you should start researching imaginary numbers, like root(-1)

Comment: @SolarMike Imaginary numbers or not, `(-2.236)**2` is never going to be equal to `-5`.

Comment: @Stef never said the result was correct, but understanding what needs to be achieved compared to what was typed...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like python, in which case exponentiation is higher precedence than unary minus.  So writing -5 ** .5 is treated as -(5 ** .5)

Answer (score 1):

In the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) table for Python, the `negative` operator (`-x`) has a lower precedence than the `exponentiation` operator (`**`).

Therefore,

```
-5 ** 0.5
```

is equivalent to

```
-(5 ** 0.5)
```